# Post a Comment to Chatter as a Another User

Tags: chatter, feeditem

I have this code working to post a FeedItem to Chatter:

```
    FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
    post.ParentId = project.Id;
    post.Body = message;
    post.Type = 'TextPost';
    post.CreatedById = '005j0000000Y3tK';
    insert post;
```

However I want my trigger to post a Comment under another FeedItem not as a new FeedItem post.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but it looks like the field

**InsertedById**

on the FeedComment object will do what you want.  There's more detail on it [here](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feedcomment.htm).  There are recipes for common Chatter tasks [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Chatter_Code_Recipes). Here's the snippet for adding a feed comment:

```
FeedComment fcomment = new FeedComment();
fcomment.FeedItemId = fId; //Id of the FeedItem on which you want to comment
fcomment.CommentBody = 'Enter your comment here';
insert fcomment;
```